# Remove the last part of the comma in foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

How can I prevent the insertion of a comma at the end of the `title3`?

```
foreach ($_POST['titles'] AS $title) {
    echo "{$title},";
};
```

Result:

```
title1,title2,title3,
```

**Update** :
It comes as a form data, this is array. Don't come this way; `title1,title2,title3,`

```
<form>
<select name="titles[]">
<option>title1</title>
<option>title2</title>
<option>title3</title>
<option>title4</title>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Just remove the last character of the result _after_ the foreach

Comment: Why not just do `implode( ',', $_POST['titles'])`? Then you wouldn't need to worry about the last comma at all.

Comment: With `substr` ? @PatrickQ

Comment: As other answers have said, you can do it via `implode()` for your use case.  For others, who may be dealing with a multi-dimensional array and can't do that, use the `for-each` to build a string in a variable, and then run the string through `trim()` to get rid of any trailing space or other specified character (like a comma)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use `implode()` - which is the equivalent to `.join()`:

```
echo implode(',', $_POST['titles']);
```

or simply:

```
echo implode($_POST['titles']);
```

if you really want to use a loop - an index is required in order to determine the last one element. a `foreach` loop does not provide any index to compare to; that's why a `for` loop is rather suitable:

```
// $titles = explode(',', $_POST['titles']);
$titles = $_POST['titles'];
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($titles); $i++) {
    echo $titles[$i];
    if($i+1 != sizeof($titles)){echo ',';}
}
```

Comment: It comes as a form data.

Comment: @PatrickQ could you be more specific about it? it looks fine to me.

Comment: "which is the equivalent to .join()" - what the sense of this statement?

Comment: @user1597430 just compared to Java/JavaScript syntax... and have updated my nostalgic syntax to the current order of arguments.

Comment: @JavaOgreniyor it seems you are confusing to input vs. the output? that `HTML` also is invalid. a `HTML` form `select` has only a single result value; the `titles[]` is non-sense. see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-select-element ...one question per question, please.

Comment: `HTML` Only example - I mean, it's form data. So comes the array format. I can't use `implode`

Comment: @JavaOgreniyor despite I don't understand why it should not be possible to `implode()` an `array`... I've added an example loop, which does about the same. that one commented out line would accept string as input. make sure to add attribute `multiple="multiple"` to the `select` element. post-fixing the name with `[]` should automatically convert it to `array`. hope this explains it well enough.

Answer (score 3):

looks like you could skip the foreach altogether and just do this:

```
echo implode(',',$_POST['titles']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `implode` instead.

```
$string = implode(',', $_POST['titles']);
```

Comment: (Docs suggest using similar argument order of explode.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers - implode() is the way to go. But if you'd rather not/keep on the path you're on...

```
$output = "";
foreach ($_POST['titles'] AS $title) {
    $output .= "{$title},";
};
echo substr($output, 0, -1);
```